# Add comma between variables

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to use this code to add a comma between two variables but getting 600 error:

```
<?php the_field('fl_venue');. ', ' .the_field('fl_address'); ?>
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't concatenate these outputs. The_field will print while get_field can be used to concat.

```
<?php the_field('fl_venue');
echo ', ';
the_field('fl_address'); ?>
```